# Create polygon label on both sides of polyline overlaping polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.3, overlapping-features, maplex

The image below represents areas which are as a final product exported to PDF as individual PDF's cut on the black line. The labels are created in a usual way.

I need to generate labels and after converting labels to annotation but in a way that I have labels on both side of black lines.

Every polygon that has black line over it should have two (or more) labels on each side of black line. The image below has been photoshopped.

Is this possible to do the same thing in ArcMap 10.3 using Maplex engine?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution that is satisfying for me.
Solution is to split polygone with my polygon grid layer using **intersect** command.
I did get some aditional attributes from grid but they are easy to erase.

Answer (score 1):

The issues seems to be that you would like several labels per polygon but ArcMap only sees one polygon to label.

Try clipping your polygon layer with your line layer. This will create multiple polygons where there was only one before. You can then manipulate maplex to label each of these polygons with its own label. If this still does not work try converting the multipart features to single part features, and try making a label for each polygon with the result.